# Easychart with views cache

Tags: 7, views, caching, charts

I have installed [easy chart](http://drupal.org/project/easychart) plugin with Drupal 7 website.

My pages are generated with views using [nodehierarchy](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodehierarchy) and [quick tabs](https://www.drupal.org/project/quicktabs) plugin.
To speed up page load, I have enabled views cache.

I noticed easy chart displays while page loads for the first time after cache is cleared. But as soon page speeds up(cached) charts are not displaying.

We have APC cache installed on our website.

Can anyone help with?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Sounds the like javascript isn't getting loaded.  Are you caching HTML markup, or just the database query?  Maybe try just caching the database call, and have it re-render the HTML markup.  Maybe it will pick up that it needs to load a JS library to work.  Assuming thats the case, of course.

Comment: I thought the same and tried keeping the data cache only. It was still same behaviour. But if I cache HTML only then it works. Which does not make sense as it was not cutting the page load time to even half. BTW I am using views argument cache. which helps clearing single page view cache on node update instead clearing all views. As I have almost 1000 pages generated using same view.

Comment: Find out if thats the case though, if its just missing the javascript, that gives you something to look for.  Manually load it on that page (via the head or page.tpl, for testing)  Break it, add that js file to the template file, then see if thats the case.  Dunno, but I have had issues with google maps due to silly things like this.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution the other way.

Created views for chart separately and inserted into my existing view through "Global view" Field.
It increased page load time a bit so for cached page from 2-3 seconds to 3-4 seconds but that is better than 30 seconds(sometimes even more based on content) without cache